# How do I use only numpy to apply filters onto images?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix, edge-detection

I would like to apply a filter/kernel to an image to alter it (for instance, perform vertical edge detection, diagonal blur, etc). I found this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) with some interesting examples of kernels.

When I look online, filters are implemented using opencv or default matplotlib/Pillow functions. I want to be able to modify an image using only numpy arrays and functions like matrix multiplication and such (There doesn't appear to be a default numpy function to perform the convolution operation.)I've tried very hard to figure it out but I keep making errors and I'm also relatively new to numpy.

I worked out this code to convert an image to greyscale:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("my_path/my_image.jpeg")
img = np.array(img.resize((180, 320)))
grey = np.zeros((320, 180))

grey_avg_array = (np.sum(img,axis=-1,keepdims=False)/3)
grey_avg_array = grey_avg_array.astype(np.uint8)

grey_image = Image.fromarray(grey_avg_array)
```

I have tried to multiply my image by a numpy array [[1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1]] to implement edge detection but that gave me a broadcasting error. What would some sample code/useful functions that can do this without errors look like?

*Also: a minor problem I've faced all day is that PIL can't display (x, x, 1) shaped arrays as images. Why is this? How do I get it to fix this? (np.squeeze didn't work)*

Comment: check out [opencv](https://opencv.org/) it has all kinds of image processing capabilities

Comment: Why don’t you want to use PIL or OpenCV? What is the purpose of implementing it with NumPy only? Did you look for descriptions of the convolution operation, how it is typically implemented? Did you try to implement it? Do that first. If you run into trouble, look at the other hundreds of questions here about implementing the convolution. If you still don’t manage to get it to work, then you can post a question here. Your question will then be well informed and useful to others. This question is neither

Answer (score 1):

Note: I would highly recommend checking out OpenCV, which has a large variety of built-in image filters.

> Also: a minor problem I've faced all day is that PIL can't display (x, x, 1) shaped arrays as images. Why is this? How do I get it to fix this? (np.squeeze didn't work)

I assume the issue here is with processing grayscale float arrays. To fix this issue, you have to convert the float arrays to `np.uint8` and use the `'L'` mode in PIL.

```
img_arr = np.random.rand(100, 100) # Our float array in the range (0, 1)
uint8_img_arr = np.uint8(img_arr * 255) # Converted to the np.uint8 type

img = Image.fromarray(uint8_img_arr, 'L') # Create PIL Image from img_arr
```

As for doing convolutions, SciPy provides [functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) for doing convolutions with kernels that you may find useful.

[image: Convolution Example]

But since we're solely using NumPy, let's implement it!

Note: To make this as general as possible, I am adding a few extra parameters that may or may not be important to you.

```py
# Assuming the image has channels as the last dimension.
# filter.shape -> (kernel_size, kernel_size, channels)
# image.shape -> (width, height, channels)
def convolve(image, filter, padding = (1, 1)):
    # For this to work neatly, filter and image should have the same number of channels
    # Alternatively, filter could have just 1 channel or 2 dimensions
    
    if(image.ndim == 2):
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=-1) # Convert 2D grayscale images to 3D
    if(filter.ndim == 2):
        filter = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(filter, axis=-1), image.shape[-1], axis=-1) # Same with filters
    if(filter.shape[-1] == 1):
        filter = np.repeat(filter, image.shape[-1], axis=-1) # Give filter the same channel count as the image
    
    #print(filter.shape, image.shape)
    assert image.shape[-1] == filter.shape[-1]
    size_x, size_y = filter.shape[:2]
    width, height = image.shape[:2]
    
    output_array = np.zeros(((width - size_x + 2*padding[0]) + 1, 
                             (height - size_y + 2*padding[1]) + 1,
                             image.shape[-1])) # Convolution Output: [(W−K+2P)/S]+1
    
    padded_image = np.pad(image, [
        (padding[0], padding[0]),
        (padding[1], padding[1]),
        (0, 0)
    ])
    
    for x in range(padded_image.shape[0] - size_x + 1): # -size_x + 1 is to keep the window within the bounds of the image
        for y in range(padded_image.shape[1] - size_y + 1):

            # Creates the window with the same size as the filter
            window = padded_image[x:x + size_x, y:y + size_y]

            # Sums over the product of the filter and the window
            output_values = np.sum(filter * window, axis=(0, 1)) 

            # Places the calculated value into the output_array
            output_array[x, y] = output_values
            
    return output_array
```

Here is an example of its usage:

Original Image (saved as `original.png`):

[image: Original Image]

```py
filter = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
], dtype=np.float32)/9.0 # Box Filter

image = Image.open('original.png')
image_arr = np.array(image)/255.0

convolved_arr = convolve(image_arr, filter, padding=(1, 1))
convolved = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(255 * convolved_arr), 'RGB') # Convolved Image
```

Convolved Image:

[image: Convolved Image]

Comment: how to show the output image  is it just convolved.show() ?  i applied same filter and output is showing like a rainbow

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- **OpenCV**, **SciPy** and **scikit-image** all use Numpy arrays as the standard way to store and manipulate images and are all largely interoperable with Numpy and each other
- as regards plotting `im` with shape `(x,y,1)`, you can just take the zeroth plane and plot that, i.e. `newim = im[...,0]`

---

When converting an RGB image to greyscale, rather than add all the RGB components up and divide by 3, you could just calculate the mean:

```
grey = np.mean(im, axis=2)
```

Actually the recommended weightings in ITU-R 601-2 are

```
L = 0.299 * Red + 0.587 * Green + 0.114 * Blue
```

So, you can use `np.dot()` to do that:

```
grey = np.dot(RGBimg[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587,0.114]).astype(np.uint8)
```

---

As regards finding vertical edges, you can do this with Numpy by subtracting each pixel from the one to its immediate right, i.e. differencing. Here is a little example, I also drew the shapes with Numpy so you can see a way to do that without using **OpenCV** since it seems to upset you so much ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
# Create a test image with a white square on black
rect = np.zeros((200,200), dtype=np.uint8)
rect[40:-40,40:-40] = 255

# Create a test image with a white circle on black
xx, yy = np.mgrid[:200, :200]
circle = (xx - 100) ** 2 + (yy - 100) ** 2
circle = (circle<4096).astype(np.uint8)*255

# Concatenate side-by-side to make our test image
im = np.hstack((rect,circle))
```

That now looks like this:

[image]

```
# Calculate horizontal differences only finding increasing brightnesses
d = im[:,1:] - im[:,0:-1]
```

[image]

```
# Calculate horizontal differences finding increasing or decreasing brightnesses
d = np.abs(im[:,1:].astype(np.int16) - im[:,0:-1].astype(np.int16))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not very efficient, but you could extend your code by the following to detect edges:

```
edge = np.zeros([322, 182])

for i in range(grey_avg_array.shape[0]-2):
    for j in range(grey_avg_array.shape[1]-2):
        edge[i+1, j+1] = np.sum(grey_avg_array[i:i+3, j:j+3]*[[1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1]])

edge = edge.astype(np.uint8)
edge_img = Image.fromarray(edge)
edge_img
```

To show image in the (say) Jupyter Notebook, you could just type the variable name (after you have done `Image.fromarray()`) as I have written above in the last line.

Comment: This is not a convolution. It actually makes no sense as values written to the output array are overwritten in a later loop iteration.